# Search operation in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to implement search operation in my project, a job portal.I am  trying to display the results on the same page,No idea how to do it. I have done following things.

**Controller**

```
$model = new SearchEmployee();

/*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
if (isset($_POST['SearchEmployee'])) {

    $model->attributes = $_POST['SearchEmployee'];

    $category   =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['category_id'];
    $skills     =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['skills'];
    $experience =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['experience'];

    $model = SearchEmployee::model()->find(array(
            'select' => array('*'), "condition" => "category_id=$category AND key_skills like'%$skills%'AND experience=$experience",

    ));

    if($model==null)
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "No Results");
        $this->render('search');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
    }

}
/*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
$this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
```

**View: a brief code**

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $model LoginForm */
/* @var $form CActiveForm  */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Search Employee';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
        'Search Employee',
);

$list = CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(),'id','title');

?>
<h1>Search Employees</h1>
<div class="form">
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'login-form',
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    )); ?>

    //Search Form//
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Skills'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'skills'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'skills'); ?>
    </div>
    //Search Form// //Result Display//
    <div class="view">

        <h1>Results</h1>

        <div class="view" id="id">

            <h1>Records Display</h1>

            <h4>
                Name:
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'skills Required'); ?>
            </h4>
            <h4>
                Skills:
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Skills Required'); ?>
            </h4>
            <h4>
                Experience:
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Skills Required'); ?>
            </h4>
            <h5>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('VIew Details'); ?>
            </h5>
        </div>

    </div>
```

It is working till the model code is executed,but while redirectig back to the page its  showing error. 'model not defined'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are obviously more errors.. let's try from the beginning:

The "model not defined" - you get because if `$model` is null, you render the `search` view withou the `$model` parameter. In the search view you try to use the `$model` variable, but of course it does not exist. you have to alter your view, so that it does not use the model if it is undefined. Or send at least an empty model in the search

`$this->render('search',new SearchEmployee);`

And you should call `$model->search()` normally after you set the attributes. But it seems that you make you own query, so you can entirely skip this line:

`$model->attributes = $_POST['SearchEmployee'];`

Comment: Asped...I miss that code while posting...have edited the question..have a look.And u r suggesting to include search right after the query,right.?